# Flutter streams on Java side

Tags: java, android, flutter

This is the Java side of my Flutter application. I am working with streams to communicate system info from android to Flutter. In this example I have a stream with two options. As it is a switch statement, they exclude one another.  What would the code look like if I wanted both to be simultaneous?

```
switch (policyStatus.priorityCategories) {
            case 128:
                events.success(result = "TOUCH SOUNDS ALLOWED");
                break;
            case 64:
                events.success(result = "MEDIA ALLOWED");
                break;
events.success(result);
```

Comment: is `events` a variable of `EventChannel.EventSink`? also what do you mean by `"if I wanted both to be simultaneous"`?

Comment: Yes, events is a variable of EventChannel.EventSink.  I mean that it is possible for them to happen at the same time. It's not just one or the other, it can be both.

Comment: in other words you are trying to call multiple times `receiveBroadcastStream` at the same time?

Comment: Yes, I guess that's correct. Is that even possible?

Comment: yes if use different names in `EventChannel` constructor

Comment: Ah, ok, many thanks for your help!